# Highcharts column chart, disable interpolation when loading from data table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to parse a HTML table and generate a column chart from it. The problem is that when I use number or date like headings, the chart adds the 'missing' years.

See the working example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ng2yvq4o/1/

The table:

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Jane</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>2006</th>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2008</th>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2009</th>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2011</th>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2012</th>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the config:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        connectNulls: false
      }
    }
});
```

I've tried to use `connectNulls: false` but it has no effect.

Is there a setting which makes the years 2007 and 2010 not appear in the chart? I would like the chart to only use the data in the HTML and use no interpolation or anything.

I hope you can help! Thanks!

Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution, use the `complete` callback to modify the names and populate `xAxis.categories` with the names:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ng2yvq4o/2/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: 'datatable',
        /**
         * Modify generated settings
         */
        complete: function (settings) {
            // We are going to create categories from each item in the series
          settings.xAxis = {
            categories: []
          };
          settings.series.map(function (series) {
              return series.data.map(function (series_item) {
                // Cast the item name to a string to prevent interpolation
              series_item[0] = String(series_item[0]);
              // Add the name to our categories:
              settings.xAxis.categories.push(series_item[0]);
              return series_item;
            });
          });
        }
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    }
});
```

I hope others have a use for this!

Greetings,
Johan